# UIWebView Won't Load

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have an app where you tap a button to take you to a table view that lists articles in an RSS feed.  Then, when you select a row in that table view it should go to a web view for the row selected.  Everything seems to be getting called but the web view doesn't appear.

Here is a link to the project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ncfpwm2vor38av/KFBNewsroom%203.zip

Comment: could you just post the relevant code? where you create the web view, how you load its content, etc...

Comment: The site is giving me fits when I try to post code for some reason.  It makes me indent each line individually.

Comment: The relevant code is in KFBViewController, ListViewController, and WebViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to push WebViewController class through null navigationcontroller instance. 
So you need to change few lines of code in ListViewController class. 
Use`[self presentModalViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
in place of`    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES]; in - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method
`

Comment: That fixed it.  I just had to change presentModalViewController to presentViewController

Comment: I do have one more thing you may be able to help with.  The RSS feed is only returning 10 results because the website has the articles across multiple pages so the app is only getting the newest 10 from the first page.  I'd like to get more than that.  The URLs are http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs and http://kyfbnewsroom.com/category/public-affairs/page/2/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding a delegate to your `UIWebView`, so you can define the [`– webView:didFailLoadWithError:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3adidFailLoadWithError%3a) and see what happens in actuality. The delegate can be the same WebViewController class instance that manages the web view. Also useful is `– webViewDidFinishLoad:`, so you know when the web view is done.

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{   
  NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", [error code]]);

      UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:@"Connection Error!" 
                                message:error.localizedErrrorDescription
                               delegate:nil 
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
}
```